# save item in mongoose and monoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I'm trying to connect to my mongoDB and to save a new user inside.

When I run the express server, the db is connected but the post request doesn't seem to happen.

Can someone check my code and help me find the problem?

**when I send the request on postmam, the postman ends up with: 'could not get response, error:socket hang up'.

I'm attaching my code below:

my server:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const authRoute = require('./routes/aouth')

dotenv.config();

//conect to db
mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost/users, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, () => console.log("connected!"))

//middleware 
app.use(express.json());

//route middleware
app.use('/api/user', authRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening on port 3000!"))
```

my User.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

my router (routes/aouth.js) :

```
  router.post('/reg', async(req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        password: req.body.password
    })
    try {

        const savedUser = await user.save()
        res.status(201).json(savedUser)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
    }

})
```

on postman my request is:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/reg
{
"password":"1234"
}

hope you guys can help me!!
Thank you!!

Comment: How do you check the database connection?

Comment: @mamunmohamed in server.js, I have a line "mongoose.connect" and on console i see "connected" each time the server is up

Comment: After ```password``` add res.end()

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I noticed that the path imported is wrong.

```
const authRoute = require('./routes/aouth')
```

Shouldn't it be?

```
const authRoute = require('./router/auth')
```

To be sure that you are connected to the database add the following lines.

```
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
```

Comment: The name of the folder is routes and inside there is a file called auth.js.. Why would it be router?  and I added those lines. It seems like the connection exists

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code to your server.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Daryl Answer, @Shir: As you mentioned `routes` folder name is correct.
But you have a file named `auth.js` & in your server file, you are importing `aouth`.

Please verify, you have correct import filename specified in server file, Else this could be an import path issue.

Comment: thank you for your comment, the mistake was only here and not in my code. So this is not the problem anyway